# How to close a specific document or file based on its name using selenium webdrive?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

the below code closes all the open excel files, is there a way to close the specific excel or word bases on the document name, please.

```
WindowsUtils.killByName("excel.exe");
```

Comment: How is the call to `WindowsUtils` related to `Selenium`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it works in selenium webdrive by importing the package, import org.openqa.selenium.os.WindowsUtils;